# Удалить элементы из строки начиная с позиции

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, строки, олимпиада

Дана строка:
`let string = '123 345\n32332'`. Строка состоит из переносов, пробелом и пр.
Необходимо удалить элементы начиная с определенной позиции.
Есть начальная позиция, обозначенная объектом:

```
let start = {row: 0, column: 0};
let end = {row: 0, column: 6}
```

(произвольные числа)

Как я понимаю, следует разбить строку на 2d массив (столбцы и строки).
Я делаю:

```
str.split('\n').map(x => x.split(''))
```

Теперь я могу пройтись по всем элементам, от первой строки до последней.

Если удаление происходит на одной и той же строке, то тут все понятно, но что делать, когда нужно удалить
с первой до третьей, например? причем, не все, но оставить несколько символов

Answer (score 1):

`но что делать, когда нужно удалить с первой до третьей, например? причем, не все, но оставить несколько символов`

Удалить в первой от column до конца
Удалить в последней от начала до column
Удалить все промежуточные (в данном случае вторую)